# "Spring is warm in France" vs. "France is warm in spring"

Tags: sentence-construction

Which sentence sounds more natural (or is correct)?

Spring is warm in France.
France is warm in spring.

Answer (score 14):

They are both fine.

The question is

Which do you want to emphasize?

In the structure of the sentence that you wrote, the word that starts the sentence (spring or France) gets the most emphasis.

So do you want to emphasize spring (in France) or France (in spring)?

In general, are you talking about spring or France? The answer to that is what you probably want to start the sentence with.

Spring is warm in France, but (spring is) cool in Australia.

France is warm in spring, but (France is) cold in Winter.

Comment: Good reasoning, can't agree with your emphasis based focus more.

Comment: "Unlike Lithuania, France is warm in Spring. Because Spring is warm in France, and cold in Lithuania." What exactly did I emphasize there?

Comment: I guess that English Language SE would talk about two objects, and either of them being made a subject, because neither is Spring warm, nor is France warm - the air is warm in Spring in France.

Answer (score -1):

Typically one would say:

`France is warm in the spring.`

Break you sentence up, and decide what is actually warm(France or Spring). Ask yourself, is spring(the season) something that can be warm?

I would say the weather during spring is warm, but not spring itself as it is just a period of time, and not a tangible thing. However, France is a country and can be considered warm.

Comment: Temperatures (and other conditions) can be associated with seasons without be a literal property of them; it is perfectly idiomatic English to say things like *Winter in New Hampshire is bitter, spring is late, and summer is mild, but autumn is brilliant*; poetically one could even say *Winter in New Hampshire is white, the spring grey, and the summer brown, but autumn is bright orange and gold* and be understood.

Comment: You're right, it very idiomatic to say such, perfectly comprehensible. My entire point, however, is that you have two non-tangible subjects(a season, and a country) and it would be more appropriate for the most tangible(the country) to have the sensory descriptions attributed to it.